# Dash bootstrap components layout creation

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I want to create a layout for a dashboard using dash_bootstrap_components that looks like this:

```
+---+---+---+
|   | 2 | 3 |
| 1 |---+---+
|   |   4   |
+---+-------+
```

Is this possible? Can someone help me figure out how to do this? Thanks :)

I tried a number of ways of getting this to work but I have found the way that dash bootstrap components works limiting. I haven't been able to get any components to span multiple rows, such as "1" in the diagram.

Comment: Hello @ben-karl , can you post the code that you tried, just to check in which direction you want to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of correctly identifying all the rows and columns in your grid.

I see the outer box as a single row containing two columns. The first column contains `1` the second column contains `2`, `3` and `4`. The second column can be further subdivided into rows and columns. Repeat the process until you've mapped all the rows and columns in your grid.

A very basic implementation of the idea using dash bootstrap components could look like this:

```
from dash import Dash, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
  dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col(1),
    dbc.Col([
      dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(2), 
        dbc.Col(3)
      ]), 
      dbc.Row(dbc.Col(4))
    ])
  ])
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Without styling it's unclear without inspecting the page that it's working so I added some simple styles

```
.row, col {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image]